# unable to load asp.net mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have downloaded a sample project developed in vs 2010 and tried to open in VS 2013 environment. I am facing an error as 
" One or more projects in the solution is not loaded "

.csproj' cannot be opened.

The project type is not supported by this installation.

How to fix and load correctly

Comment: Which version of VS2013 do you have?

Answer (score 0):

See whether the supporting references are available in your project or not , Update the reference using mebmatrix or nuget , this scenario could be there if you are opening Azure Project in Visual Studio but Azure SDK is not installed for related VS version .